# Python check for boolean

Tags: python

```
months = ['January',
      'February',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'August',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December']
checker = False
def valid_month(month):
    for mon in months:
        if mon.lower() == month.lower():
            print mon
            checker = True

    print "out of the loop, checker = " + str(checker)
    if checker is False:
      print None

print valid_month("jaNuary")
```

This should just print January.
But for some reason the output looks like this:

```
January
out of the loop, checker = True
None
```

checker is true, then why does it pass the if statement? which is "if checker is False:"

Comment: Initialising `checker` outside the function is a bad idea, and it never returns anything.

Comment: The `None` at the end is printed because `valid_month("jaNuary")` returns None ; not  because checker is False. You are printing the return value of function. If you replace it with `checker is True` you should see two `None`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't return a value from `valid_month`. At the end of the function, add

```
def valid_month(month):
    #existing code here

    return checker
```

---

You should also bring the `checker = False` line *into* your function.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note, you can simplify this by using the `calendar` module to create a mapping of lowercase month name->proper month name, then using that as a lookup for your print, eg:

```
from calendar import month_name

VALID_MONTHS = {m.lower(): m for m in month_name[1:]}

def valid_month(month):
    return VALID_MONTHS.get(month.lower())

print valid_month('JaNuary')
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing can be reduced to one line and **without** the need for list comprehensions like in the other answers.

```
print "jaNuary".capitalize() in months
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all of those loops. Make your `valid_month` method look like this:

```
def valid_month(month):
    return month.lower() in [m.lower() for m in months]

if valid_month("jaNuary"):
    print("jaNuary")
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers state, you need to return something from your function in order to print something other than `None`.

You're printing None currently because `valid_month` returns None, so the final `print` statement is printing the return value.

With that said, there's another issue in here:

When you initialize a variable outside of a function in the global scope, you cannot do anything with that variable in of the function.

If you want to modify *or access* a global variable, you need to start your function with

```
global var_name
```

where `var_name` is the variable name.

Or you could just bring the variable into the function, since it's not needed anywhere else and should be returned from the function, as a general best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the whole thing with **one line**. Say `month = jaNuaRY`

```
status = "valid" if month.lower() in months else "invalid"
```

So entries in `months` should be as you have given above. If you are not sure, then,

```
status = "valid" if month.lower() in (m.lower() for m in months) else "invalid"
```